# Why swift GCD not work in tableview cell imageView

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, asynchronous

I made a chat app. When I chatting and post image message to A man. I check my image upload successful,and download to local document failed. A man's view just have imageView with clear background.No image to show,and I click back to previous view,then go back chat view. The image show up. what's happen? how to let image download to local immediatly? Thanks!!

This is my download function code:

```
func ImageFromUrl(imageView:UIImageView,url:String) {

let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("\(Image)/")

let fileName = url + ".jpg"
let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

let urlString = URL(string: url)

if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
{
    imageView.image = image
    return
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: urlString!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch

    if data != nil
    {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        {
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.001)
                {
                    do {
                        try jpegData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                    } catch {
                        debug(object: error)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                debug(object:"file already exists")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = image//UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell: CustomTableViewCell = CustomTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

if cell.isRight == false {  //A man's cell View

ImageFromUrl(imageView:cell.imageView,url:imageUrl)
//tableView.reloadRow(at:indexPath, with: .automatic)
//tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
//tableView.reloadRow(UInt(contents.count-1), inSection: 0, with: .automatic)

}


}
```

Comment: you need to refresh the tableView after you get back to main queue.

Comment: Unless you're doing it yourself for fun, you misewell use https://github.com/kean/Nuke or https://github.com/kiavashfaisali/KFSwiftImageLoader

Answer (score 0):

Since this is being pushed to GCD the table will finish updating while the image is loaded. Therefore you will need reload the data in the table view.

Change:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    imageView.image = image//UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

to:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    imageView.image = image//UIImage(data: data!)
    self.tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

But this won't be enough, as the image will be recreated each time `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is called and you will be caught in an infinite loop. I would recommend subclassing UITableViewCell to create your own cell that contains an `image` property. Then you can tell ImageFromURL(_) to save the image to the cell's `image` property, and then reload the view.

Comment: Please don't reload the ENTIRE table when the image in one cell needs to be updated.  If you can't get the cell itself to realize when the image is available and change it's image view, then reload the one row you need (using `func reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)`)

Comment: sorry, I use  tableView.reloadRow(at: indexPath, with: .automatic) ,when I scroll up that tableview also reload other cell again, how can make image cell reload once.

Comment: That's another question in itself. I would set a flag `pictureAlreadyLoaded: Bool` in the cell's class and set it to true when the picture is set and the row reloaded. Then check that flag before you call reloadRows.